# How to get p-value and confident interval in LogisticRegression with sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am building a multinomial logistic regression with sklearn (LogisticRegression). But after it finishes, how can I get a p-value and confident interval of my model? It only appears that sklearn only provides coefficient and intercept.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 15):

The short answer is that sklearn LogisticRegression does not have a built in method to calculate p-values.  Here are a few other posts that discuss solutions to this, however.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928275/find-p-value-significance-in-scikit-learn-linearregression

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306341/python-sklearn-how-to-calculate-p-values

Answer (score 14):

One way to get confidence intervals is to bootstrap your data, say, $B$ times and fit logistic regression models $m_i$ to the dataset $B_i$ for $i = 1, 2, ..., B$. This gives you a distribution for the parameters you are estimating, from which you can find the confidence intervals.

Answer (score 6):

This is still not implemented and not planned as it seems out of scope of sklearn, as per Github discussion  [#6773](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6773) and [#13048](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13048).

However, the documentation on [linear models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) now mention that (P-value estimation note):

- It is theoretically possible to get p-values and confidence intervals for coefficients in cases of regression without penalization.
- The [statsmodels package](https://pypi.org/project/statsmodels/) natively supports this.
- Within sklearn, one could use bootstrapping.

It appears that it is possible to modify the LinearRegression class to calculate p-values from linear algebra, as per this [Github code](https://gist.github.com/brentp/5355925).