# Is there a documentation where it is explained why scikit-learn does not provide p-values?

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there a documentation, paper etc. where it is explained why *scikit-learn* does not provide p-values/confidence levels ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39066567/6256241), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27928275/6256241), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44495667/6256241), [4](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/15398/73128))? Note: I'm not asking about opinions, but about documentation. For example the `R` package `lme4` does not provide p-values either, [but has a FAQ point](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#why-doesnt-lme4-display-denominator-degrees-of-freedomp-values-what-other-options-do-i-have)  about this. [On the official scikit-learn website](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) I found no explanation for this desicion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scoring function in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html) package which is used in a feature selection procedure. This function first computes F-score and then converts it to p-value.

Answer (score 0):

Several feature selection techniques return p values, e.g. ANOVA, chi2,..:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression